# I can build to my devices just fine, but I get all these errors when building to the simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ipad

I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong and more importantly how to fix it. Can someone please help me? It appears that I'm doing something wrong with the frameworks, but they are all included. More importantly, these errors only appear when I use the iOS simulator.

```
Ld /Users/dannyperski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Exponential_Invasion-enydgqkwfmhjchfdukokblajnunh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Exponential\ Invasion.app/Exponential\ Invasion normal x86_64
    cd "/Users/dannyperski/Documents/GitHub/exponential-invasion/Exponential Invasion"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.4.sdk -L/Users/dannyperski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Exponential_Invasion-enydgqkwfmhjchfdukokblajnunh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/dannyperski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Exponential_Invasion-enydgqkwfmhjchfdukokblajnunh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/dannyperski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Exponential_Invasion-enydgqkwfmhjchfdukokblajnunh/Build/Intermediates/Exponential\ Invasion.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Exponential\ Invasion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Exponential\ Invasion.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=7.0 -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/dannyperski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Exponential_Invasion-enydgqkwfmhjchfdukokblajnunh/Build/Intermediates/Exponential\ Invasion.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Exponential\ Invasion.build/Exponential\ Invasion.app.xcent -framework Twitter -framework Social -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore -framework Accounts -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/dannyperski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Exponential_Invasion-enydgqkwfmhjchfdukokblajnunh/Build/Intermediates/Exponential\ Invasion.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Exponential\ Invasion.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Exponential\ Invasion_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/dannyperski/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Exponential_Invasion-enydgqkwfmhjchfdukokblajnunh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Exponential\ Invasion.app/Exponential\ Invasion

ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter (3 slices)ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Social.framework/Social (3 slices)

ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit (3 slices)ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation (3 slices)

ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics (3 slices)ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore (3 slices)

ld: warning: ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts (3 slices)ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AudioToolbox.framework/AudioToolbox (3 slices)

ld: warning: ignoring file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/AVFoundation.framework/AVFoundation (3 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient", referenced from:
      -[iPhoneView viewDidLoad] in iPhoneView.o
      -[iPadView viewDidLoad] in iPadView.o
  "_CGAffineTransformIdentity", referenced from:
      -[jsJiggle startJiggle] in jsJiggle.o
      ___23-[jsJiggle startJiggle]_block_invoke in jsJiggle.o
      ___22-[jsJiggle stopJiggle]_block_invoke in jsJiggle.o
  "_CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation", referenced from:
      -[Levels switchLeft] in Levels.o
      -[Levels offsetSwitchLeft] in Levels.o
      -[Levels switchRight] in Levels.o
      -[Levels offsetSwitchRight] in Levels.o
      -[Levels setLevelPosition] in Levels.o
      -[proAlertView moveRight] in proAlertView.o
      -[proAlertView moveLeft] in proAlertView.o
      ...
  "_CGAffineTransformRotate", referenced from:
      -[jsJiggle startJiggle] in jsJiggle.o
      ___23-[jsJiggle startJiggle]_block_invoke in jsJiggle.o
  "_CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGColorSpaceRelease", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGContextAddArcToPoint", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRoundedRect:inContext:withRadius:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGContextAddEllipseInRect", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGContextBeginPath", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRoundedRect:inContext:withRadius:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGContextClearRect", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGContextClip", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGContextClosePath", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRoundedRect:inContext:withRadius:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGContextDrawLinearGradient", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGContextDrawPath", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGContextMoveToPoint", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRoundedRect:inContext:withRadius:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGContextSetAlpha", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGContextSetFillColorWithColor", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGContextSetLineWidth", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGGradientRelease", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGRectGetMaxX", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRoundedRect:inContext:withRadius:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGRectGetMaxY", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRoundedRect:inContext:withRadius:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGRectGetMidX", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRoundedRect:inContext:withRadius:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGRectGetMidY", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRoundedRect:inContext:withRadius:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGRectGetMinX", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRoundedRect:inContext:withRadius:] in proAlertView.o
  "_CGRectGetMinY", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRoundedRect:inContext:withRadius:] in proAlertView.o
  "_NSClassFromString", referenced from:
      +[MKiCloudSync start] in MKiCloudSync.o
  "_NSLog", referenced from:
      +[MKiCloudSync start] in MKiCloudSync.o
  "_NSUbiquitousKeyValueStoreDidChangeExternallyNotification", referenced from:
      +[MKiCloudSync start] in MKiCloudSync.o
      +[MKiCloudSync dealloc] in MKiCloudSync.o
  "_NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
      +[MKiCloudSync updateFromiCloud:] in MKiCloudSync.o
      +[MKiCloudSync start] in MKiCloudSync.o
      +[MKiCloudSync dealloc] in MKiCloudSync.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioPlayer", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iPhoneView.o
      objc-class-ref in iPadView.o
      objc-class-ref in Levels.o
      objc-class-ref in About.o
      objc-class-ref in Levels_iPad.o
      objc-class-ref in About_iPad.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AVAudioSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iPhoneView.o
      objc-class-ref in iPadView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAKeyframeAnimation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UIView+I7ShakeAnimation.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAutoreleasePool", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBundle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iPhoneView.o
      objc-class-ref in iPadView.o
      objc-class-ref in Levels.o
      objc-class-ref in About.o
      objc-class-ref in Levels_iPad.o
      objc-class-ref in About_iPad.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableArray", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UIView+I7ShakeAnimation.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSNotificationCenter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MKiCloudSync.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Levels.o
      objc-class-ref in Levels_iPad.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURL", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iPhoneView.o
      objc-class-ref in iPadView.o
      objc-class-ref in Levels.o
      objc-class-ref in About.o
      objc-class-ref in Levels_iPad.o
      objc-class-ref in About_iPad.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSUbiquitousKeyValueStore", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MKiCloudSync.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSUserDefaults", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iPhoneView.o
      objc-class-ref in iPadView.o
      objc-class-ref in Levels.o
      objc-class-ref in Levels_iPad.o
      objc-class-ref in MKiCloudSync.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSValue", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UIView+I7ShakeAnimation.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIAlertView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_proAlertView in proAlertView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIColor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Levels.o
      objc-class-ref in Levels_iPad.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIDevice", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Exponential_InvasionAppDelegate.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Levels.o
      objc-class-ref in Levels_iPad.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIImageView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in proAlertView.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIScreen", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Levels.o
      objc-class-ref in Levels_iPad.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Levels.o
      objc-class-ref in proAlertView.o
      objc-class-ref in Levels_iPad.o
      l_OBJC_$_CATEGORY_UIView_$_I7ShakeAnimation in UIView+I7ShakeAnimation.o
      objc-class-ref in jsJiggle.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_iPhoneView in iPhoneView.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_iPadView in iPadView.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Levels in Levels.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_About in About.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_Levels_iPad in Levels_iPad.o
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_About_iPad in About_iPad.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIAlertView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_proAlertView in proAlertView.o
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_UIViewController", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_iPhoneView in iPhoneView.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_iPadView in iPadView.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Levels in Levels.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_About in About.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_Levels_iPad in Levels_iPad.o
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_About_iPad in About_iPad.o
  "_UIApplicationMain", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
  "_UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext", referenced from:
      -[proAlertView drawRect:] in proAlertView.o
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in main.o
      CFString in iPhoneView.o
      CFString in iPhoneView.o
      CFString in iPhoneView.o
      CFString in iPhoneView.o
      CFString in iPhoneView.o
      CFString in iPhoneView.o
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the frameworks to all targets. To do so, select the framework and check the boxes in the file inspector below *Target Membership*.

Comment: Can you include a screenshot to show what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

You might be selecting the simulator which do not support 64-bit. The libraries you are using requires iPhone 5s/6 simulator.